# Privacy field is returned blank for photo post in Facebook api

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app is making posts on behalf of the users, some of the posts are uploading photos. Sometimes Facebook treats the post as a photo post and show it inside the app album on the user timeline but in that case, when I try to get the post information using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/XX_XX?access_token=....

I get the privacy field blank as follows:

```
"privacy":{
"allow":"",
"deny":"",
"description":"",
"value":""
}
```

Although the photo was posted by the app and the access token is valid.

Any idea why is this happening? Or how can I get the app album privacy?

Comment: I would test this further and if you can pin it down to specific scenario, then I would report this as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) if you believe this is an issue with the API.